# Unable to save trained tensorflow model due to TypeError on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working through [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) official jupyter notebook from tensorflow on github, about eager few shot learning, hosted on google colab.

I was hoping to save and store this custom model after training, but I get the following error
when executing

> tf.saved_model.save(detection_model, save_path)
>
> --> 140       raise TypeError('Expected Operation, Variable, or Tensor, got ' + str(x))
> 141
> 142     for y in outputs:

TypeError: Expected Operation, Variable, or Tensor, got block4

I am running the original notebook without modifications, as hosted on the colab virtual environment. It runs on TF 2.2 and this particular error should have been resolved with TF2.2 .

When trying the keras .save method it would obviously complain that I dont have a keras model.